# Is render to texture available in blender?

Tags: blender, 3dsmax, rendertexture

I don't know is render to texture available in blender like in 3dsmax if it is available please tell me step by step method to do that thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render to texture is also known as texture 'baking', which is the term used in blender.

The blender manual has some [info on baking](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/baking.html) and you can find several [tutorials on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%20tutorial%20baking)